# Import data from Excel with SQL Developer 4.2

Tags: oracle, import, oracle-sqldeveloper, import-from-excel

How can I import data from Excel files using SQL Developer 4.2?

I have been following [these instructions](https://youtu.be/wWIhGWXEZC4) (from [SQL Developer 4.1 New Features - Import Data Wizard](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/sqldev-41-newfeatures-2372787.html)), which used to work in SQL Developer 4.1.x but, apparently, SQL Developer 4.2 can only import from text files (delimited or CSV):

[image: Data Import Wizard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pick your file first.

Where it says 'Data Import File' click 'browse.' Then pick your XLS or XLSX file.